# jgit occurs Packfile is truncated when use Git.cloneRepository

Tags: java, eclipse, jgit

When I use eclipse jgit api Git.cloneRepository() clone a big repo ,it occurs java.io.EOFException:Packfile is truncated.
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1241) .

My code :

```
CloneCommand cmd = Git.cloneRepository();
cmd.setDirectory(repo)
cmd.setGitDir()
cmd.setURI()
cmd.setCredentialsProvider()
cmd.setProgressMonitor()
cmd.setTimeout(600000)
git = cmd.call()
```

it occurs trunck errors in below:
 Receiving objects:  94% (143964/152511)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

finally I resolve this question use ssh .notes this repo is beyond 4.5G !
**If your repo is big enough ,eg big than 4G ,don't clone with jgit using HTTP format URI, you ought to use SSH URI to clone with jgit api,otherwise you will got packfile is truncated error .even you use the lastest jgit version**

```
CloneCommand cmd = Git.cloneRepository()
cmd.setDirecotry()
cmd.setGitDir()
cmd.setURI()
cmd.setCredentialsProvider(new CredentialsProvider(){

})
cmd.setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor())
cmd.setTimeout(600000)
cmd.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback(){
    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport){
         SshTransport ssh = (SshTransport)transport
         ssh.setSshSessionFactory(new JshConfigSessionFactory(){
              @Override
              protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host host,Session 
              session){
                  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no"); 
              }
              @Override
              protected JSch getJSch(Final OpenSshConfig.Host hc,FS fs) 
              throws JSchException {
                  JSch jsch = super.getJSch(hc,fs);
                  jsch.removeAllIdentity();
                  jsch.addIdentity("/path/to/your/private key")//note must be 
//a rsa private key format,otherwise you will get the bad private key error 
                  return jsch;

              } 

         })
    } 
})
git = cmd.call();
```

Comment: refer https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepositoryWithAuthentication.java , for complete cmd.setCredentialsProvider(new CredentialsProvider(){

})

Comment: Is this a limitation of JSch? If yes, does it work with Apache MINA sshd as SSH client?